# Manga about a girl who lives her life as if she was in a manga

Tags: story-identification, comics, manga, webcomics

This girl with short brown hair and brown eyes wakes up. It’s her first day of school (high school, I forgot what grade she was in. Also I believe that her old middle school was called *Jon Jin Middle School*? Or I don’t know if that is the name of the high school), when she wakes up to put in her uniform she gets confused. She gets confused because the uniform was something out of a manga story.

She asks her mom if this was the correct uniform and her mom says that yes it is the correct uniform. So she gets confused but puts on the uniform and when she heads out, she’s sees across from her apartment with a girl who was gorgeous with the same uniform (I don’t remember what happened when she saw her. Later on she finds out that that was her childhood best friend and still is)

She starts walking to her high school only to figure out that her high school she was going to attend didn’t exist, so she got confused. She then went to find a map and started looking for her school. And when she was walking a car stopped and two guys came out a kid with I believe blonde or orange hair and another guy with white hair. And the driver says that if she can show them the way to school.

Once the driver left she asked the two guys if they know where her school was and the kid with blonde/orange hair responded with that there was not school with that name. And then when she gets to the school with the uniform she was wearing she asks if she attends that school and she does.

The last time I read it, which was recently, it had 52 chapters so far so it might have more like at least 1 or 2 more chapters so it might 52-56 chapters total.

Comment: Do you remember if there was any science fiction elements in this story? Something to explain why she no longer remembers these things?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: So she's a normal girl who basically wakes up in a manga story? Is that the premise

Comment: I’m trying to look for the title of this manga, this description is about what happens in the beginning of it, I did not finish this manga and am asking if anyone knew the name of this manga by describing the first few events, or if they know similar story’s that I can look into.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to make the title generic noise and add in that you're looking for it. We know you're looking for it.

Comment: The name of the school looks like in Korean, not Japanese nor Chinese. It's good to have enough in-universe elements, how about more out-of-universe detail? Do you remember where you read this on? Around what year? Is the story all in color? Note that as a Q&A site, we will only identify this work, but not recommending similar works.

Comment: @Valorum may sound late. But I can answer this question. It sound confusing but the girl wakes up and the world change not her original one(like a parallel world). She can go back to her original world in just 1 day only and everything about her in current world will stay but no one remember her when she is absent. When she is back memory will come back. The answer is Inso's law

Comment: @Someoneuseless - Answerability wasn't the issue here, but rather whether it's on topic. Parallel worlds seems pretty fantasy to me

Comment: @Valorum There are a chapter which she dissapear in the 2nd world and come back to the first world. But outside of that chapter this do seem like a romance novel with MC interfer with FL and her capture target make them love her maybe like [Bakarina](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/i-reincarnated-into-an-otome-game-as-a-villainess-with-only-destruction-flags)

Answer (score 5):

This is [Inso's law](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=154214)

What Ashley describe is in chapter 1. Her role seem to be female lead(FL) friend, a.k.a a mob character. In this new world, she befriend with the female protagonist and her capture target. The plot start at middle school and then got a time skip to highschool.

Syponisis:

> “I just want to live a normal life, why is this happening to me!” Your average student Ham Dan, whose hobby was reading “Law of Insomnia” wakes up to a beautiful novel like heroine. But even in the world of fantasy novels, her role is no different. Stuck as the childhood friend of the heroine, her normal everyday life comes to an end, becoming more twisted by her strong character.

Cover image

[image]

It is about Ham Dan get transport to parallel world after a sleep. Her parent is still the same, except it was added novel element(irealistic power like jumping from 3rd floor, character don't exist in real world,...) there. She had a special day where if she sleep, the world will return back to normal but the other world still exist . The FL and other forget about her existance and only remember once she got back to their world.