# Looking for a manga/manhwa where a girl wakes up in a romance book as the female lead's best friend

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read some of this a few months ago. The female lead has short hair. She goes to school and ends up befriending all of the male leads. She's always seemed a bit distant, and they end up learning that every year, she disappears one day and nobody remembers her. She's scared she'll never see them again or something, so she stays distant(?)

It was pretty long into the story from what I remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[My Life as an Internet Novel](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/my-life-as-an-internet-novel)*, aka *Inso's Law*. It is licensed by [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/my-life-as-an-internet-novel/info).

> Every novel has the usual cast: a gorgeous heroine, handsome boys vying for her attention, and a homely best friend at the heroine’s side. Dani, an ordinary student and avid reader of internet novels, is all too familiar with these tropes. But she never imagined that one day she’d wake up at the center of one herself! Her new fictional world is complete with a beautiful best friend named Yeoryung, and **four impossibly good-looking boys who all happen to be in her class. Dani is determined to stay out of the way and not get involved in the twists and turns of the plot**. But is she really just the sidekick -- or is Dani actually the leading lady? Anything is possible in the world of a novel!

[image: Cover]

The cover shows the protagonist, Dani, in the middle, and she has short hair. The male leads are above her, and Ban Yeo Ryeong, the beautiful presumed-heroine, to the right.

Dani is indeed distant, due to a combination of not feeling like she belongs in this other world, not wanting to get mixed up in a webnovel's plot, and assuming that they're actually interested in Ban Yeo Ryeong, since she's clearly the heroine.

She does disappear from the novel world once a day. I don't recall exactly where this is first mentioned, probably somewhere around chapter 40-70, and lasts for a few chapters.

Comment: Also the answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/232164; unaccepted, but definitely the same story.